# How to remove part of string from list

Tags: python

I have a file with data and i want to count numbers of macaddress:
file.txt:

> Blockquote

**D8:6C:E9:3C:77:FF**;2016/01/10 14:02:47

**D8:6C:E9:3C:77:FF**;2016/01/10 14:02:47

D8:6C:E9:43:52:BF;2016/01/10 13:41:29

F0:82:61:31:6B:88;2016/01/10 13:43:41

8C:10:D4:D4:83:E5;2016/01/10 13:44:35

54:64:D9:E8:64:36;2016/01/10 13:46:13

18:1E:78:5A:CD:25;2016/01/10 13:46:27

18:1E:78:5A:D7:A5;2016/01/10 13:46:35

**54:64:D9:75:1B:4B**;2016/01/10 13:30:28

**54:64:D9:75:1B:4B**;2016/01/10 13:30:28
etc....

I put it to the list :

`with open ('file.txt') as f:
    mac = f.read().splitlines()
    my_dic = {i:mac.count(i) for i in mac} 
    print my_dic`

output:

{'18:1E:78:5A:D7:A5;2016/01/10 13:46:35': 1, 'D8:6C:E9:3C:77:FF;2016/01/10 14:02:47': 2, '54:64:D9:E8:64:36;2016/01/10 13:46:13': 1, 'D8:6C:E9:43:52:BF;2016/01/10 13:41:29': 1, 'F0:82:61:31:6B:88;2016/01/10 13:43:41': 1, '54:64:D9:75:1B:4B;2016/01/10 13:30:28': 2, '18:1E:78:5A:CD:25;2016/01/10 13:46:27': 1, '8C:10:D4:D4:83:E5;2016/01/10 13:44:35': 1}

how to rid of dates because i expected:

{'18:1E:78:5A:D7:A5 : 1, 'D8:6C:E9:3C:77:FF : 2, '54:64:D9:E8:64:36 : 1, 'D8:6C:E9:43:52:BF : 1, 'F0:82:61:31:6B:88 : 1, '54:64:D9:75:1B:4B : 2, '18:1E:78:5A:CD:25 : 1, '8C:10:D4:D4:83:E5 : 1}

Answer (score 0):

Write a [regexp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) that match this date format, and use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) to remove the matching part.